# Will iOS take backup of documents folder if iCloud is disabled against app id?

Tags: ios, icloud

I am working on app creating thousands of file and folder in documents folder. I do not want to take the backup on iCloud. I have disabled the iCloud against app id. Will iCloud use auto app sync feature against my app?

Comment: But why don't you use Caches Directory instead?

Comment: because i dont want them to be deleted, I just do not want these to be synced on iCloud!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: Thanks Suresh! I will have to modify the code. Now app is ready to submit. I am thinking that if app backup is not taken if iCloud is disabled then I should not use the code in above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that disabling iCloud Support against app_id has no connection with iCould backup/restore feature, If i want to avoid my data being stored on iCloud than i can either use caches or i have to explicitly pass NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey key to the file as pointed out by @Suresh